# Recoll integration in Gnome Search Shell

Tags: gnome-shell, recoll

my system is running Ubuntu 21.04 with Gnome 3.38.5 and X11 windowing system

I have installed Recoll 1.31.0 and gssp-recoll-1.1.0 and enabled recoll in the search setting.

When I type something in the gnome search box, I don't get any results from Recoll.

any ideas on how to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you enable Recoll in the search settings? Is that in Settings - Search?

Comment: I did nothing special. I just installed and yes, it's in Settings/Search.